# Use pk from url in django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my django app I have a table which contains a button that redirects you to a form like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'employee:delivered_docket_form' docket.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary">Create Delivered Docket</a>
```

Urls.py

```
path('delivered-docket/add/<int:pk>/', DeliveredDocketFormView.as_view(),
                                        name='delivered_docket_form')
```

Views.py

```
@method_decorator([login_required, employee_required], name='dispatch')
class DeliveredDocketFormView(CreateView):
    model = DeliveredDocket
    form_class = DeliveredDocketeditform
    template_name = 'packsapp/employee/docketDeliveredForm.html'

    def form_valid (self, form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        product.save()
        data = form.cleaned_data
        print("form data is ", data)
        print("pk is ",self.kwargs['pk'])
        messages.success(self.request, 'The Delivered Docket was created with success!')
        return redirect('employee:delivered_docket_table')
```

I am able to access the `pk` in the views function by `self.kwargs['pk']` but how can I access it in the formclass. Here's my form

Forms.py

```
class DeliveredDocketeditform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DeliveredDocket
        fields = '__all__'
```

What I want to add in the form is something like this:

```
class DeliveredDocketeditform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DeliveredDocket
        fields = '__all__'


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['sender'].queryset = Warehouse.objects.id(id = ??)
```

How do I get pk to this query ??

Comment: Where do you want to access the pk (in which method) and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @IainShelvington I want to intialize a field(sender) in this form using super

Comment: Why not pass "sender" in `DeliveredDocketeditform.get_initial()` to initialise the form with the value you want? Should the field be editable?

Comment: @IainShelvington I don't know how to do that, please elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override [`get_initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial) method  in your view to pass initial data to the form:

```
class DeliveredDocketFormView(CreateView):
    model = DeliveredDocket
    form_class = DeliveredDocketeditform
    template_name = 'packsapp/employee/docketDeliveredForm.html'

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['sender'] = Warehouse.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return initial
```